# How to create 2D jagged array

Tags: .net, jagged-arrays

In my code an array is declared as follows

```
private Object[,] cellInfos = new Object[20, 10];
```

I need to convert it into Jagged array so I wrote following code

```
private Object[][] cellInfos = {
    new Object[20],
    new Object[10]
};
```

But it gave me a array with 2 items each of type array.

I need to create 2D array where `new Object[20]` would be first column and `new Object[10]` would be the second one.

Comment: "But it gave me a array with 2 items each of type array." - isn't that exactly what a jagged array (=an array of arrays) is?

Comment: so can't I have an array where new Object[20] would be first column and new Object[10] would be the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something more like this:

```
object[][] cellInfos = new object[20][];
for (int i = 0; i < cellInfos.Length; i++)
{
   cellInfos[i] = new object[10];
}
```